# finger daemon / nc fowarding error

Tags: daemon, hostname, netcat, nc

For an assignment I'm trying to properly send a buffer overflow exploit with ncat in order gain root access on a vulnerable machine set up by the professor. I feel I created my egg right but I keep getting the same error when I pipe my egg exploit file to ncat. I've tried researching this error but have found nothing to what it means or how to overcome it. I'm not sure if my command is the best way to send an exploit to the finger daemon.

My command

```
cat egg | nc hostname port
```

the ouput with error at the end

```
Welcome to an eggie Linux version 4.9.0-3-686-pae at hostname.lan !

 19:20:41 up 15 days,  4:29,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00

fingerd: forwarding not allowed
```

Comment: As we don't know what you're doing (supposed some call to finger/fingerd), there is not much to tell you.

Comment: Agree to @stoney, probably this Q shouldn't be asked in the first place. It's student's job to research the behavior of a black box in pen test; besides, nobody knows what your payload is supposed to do, or how finger daemon is supposed to react.